# Is it possible to store a field (not its contents) as a variable in FileMaker?

Tags: variable-assignment, filemaker, lookup-tables

I'm starting to clean through some old code in a FileMaker database. Someone has the following script in there which allows users to upload a file to a container field. The script determines which field to store the file in based on the Script Parameter.

```
Set Error Capture [On]
Allow User Abort [Off]

Set Variable [$ScriptParameter; Value: Get (ScriptParameter)]

If [$ScriptParameter = "Clean"]
    Insert File [Insert; Display content; Never compress; Target:Inspections::cert_Clean]
Else If [$ScriptParameter = "C of C"]
    Insert File [Insert; Display content; Never compress; Target:Inspections::cert_C of C]
Else If [$ScriptParameter = "Hardness"]
    Insert File [Insert; Display content; Never compress; Target:Inspections::cert_Hardness]
...
.
.
End If
```

It's more or less a lookup table. I would like to pull the actual `Insert File` function out of the lookup table, and just use a variable that stores the target field. Then have the `Insert File` get its Target from the variable. Is it possible to store the field itself, rather than its contents, with `Set Variable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A script parameter is always a **value**, not a **field reference**.

The other thing is that the `Insert File` script step will **not** let you specify the target field dynamically; you must "bake" the target field into the step.

What you could do, though, is insert the file into a variable first, then use the `Set Field By Name` script step to place the inserted file in the target field as determined by the script parameter. But then you would need to pass the target field's **name** (as Text) as the script parameter - for example, make the parameter:

```
GetFieldName ( Target:Inspections::cert_Clean )
```

for the first field, and so on. Then your script could do simply:

```
Insert File [ $insertedFile ]
Set Field By Name [ Get ( ScriptParameter ); $insertedFile ]
```

---

P.S. This step:

```
Set Variable [$ScriptParameter; Value: Get (ScriptParameter)]
```

does not accomplish anything except wasting CPU cycles and memory. the script parameter itself is already a variable; you can refer to it directly.

Comment: Okay thank you, I appreciate the help. Thanks for the `Set Variable` tip!